# octave in ubuntu: 'rm' undefined near line 1 column 1

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, octave

I am running octave in ubuntu. I got the following problem while trying to delete a file:

```
>> ls
cos1.dat  cos.dat  datFile.grc top_block.py
>> rm cos1.dat
error: 'rm' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

However, everything is OK in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your file with

```
>> delete("cos1.dat")
```